# reading rasters in r using terra package

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, r, terra

Using the R terra package for the first time after many years using the raster package. Stuck on the basics.

Trying to read DEM raster into r and reproject it. The raster is in ESRI grid format and can be downloaded [here](https://www.sciencebase.gov/catalog/item/4fb5495ee4b04cb937751d6d).

I previously asked [this](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-geo/2020-February/027932.html) question on r-sig-geo.

And had working solution with raster

```
dem_raster<-raster("/Users/mypath/w001001.adf")
```

Attempting the same with terra::rast

```
dem_terra<-rast("/Users/mypath/w001001.adf")
```

And plotting the results side by side...

[image]

Printing the details for the two rasters

```
dem_raster

class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 8827, 10224, 90247248  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 1000, 1000  (x, y)
extent     : -5762000, 4462000, -3920000, 4907000  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=laea +lat_0=-100 +lon_0=6370997 +x_0=45 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
source     : w001001.adf 
names      : w001001 
values     : -76, 5930  (min, max)
attributes :
         ID COUNT
 from:  -76     2
  to : 5930     1

dem_terra

class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 8827, 10224, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 1000, 1000  (x, y)
extent      : -5762000, 4462000, -3920000, 4907000  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=laea +lat_0=-100 +lon_0=6370997 +x_0=45 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
source      : w001001.adf 
name        : VALUE 
min value   :   -76 
max value   :  5930
```

How do I get rast to read in the ESRI grid values correctly?

Comment: One question per post please, then we have a nice set of single questions with best answers! I've answered your first, if you can cut your second Q out of here and paste it into a new post we can look at that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `raster` and `terra` show that this is a categorical raster because it has a Raster Attribute Table (RAT). But these are different for AI GRID than for the GTiff that I have tested and developed with. The AI GRID attributes are not correctly interpreted and they are not that useful. All the RAT adds is the counts of the unique values. If I recall well, that is the case for all integer AI GRID files (my memory is blurry, I rarely encounter one of them these days). In the current development version of `terra` the RAT is ignored in cases like this and the `SpatRaster` is not categorical.

@Spacedman trick to add zero works fine, because the levels are dropped when doing arithmetic.

You can install the development version with

`install.packages('terra', repos='https://rspatial.r-universe.dev')`

`plot(x)` still looks a bit odd, because taking a sample with GDAL seems to mess up the NODATA value for this file. It appears to work well for all other purposes.

Comment: can you confirm this has been sorted out in the new `terra` versions? I think I still have a similar issue. Using `rast` to read a DEM file returns a factor raster which I can then convert using `as.numeric` and then works fine.

Answer (score 2):

The raster package fails for me with that data:

```
> r = raster(f)
proj_create: Error -22: lat_0, lat_1 or lat_2 >= 90
proj_create: Error -22: lat_0, lat_1 or lat_2 >= 90
Error in .rasterObjectFromFile(x, band = band, objecttype = "RasterLayer",  : 
  Cannot create a RasterLayer object from this file.
```

Oh well. `terra` works:

```
> r = rast(f)
> r
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 8827, 10224, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 1000, 1000  (x, y)
extent      : -5762000, 4462000, -3920000, 4907000  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=laea +lat_0=-100 +lon_0=6370997 +x_0=45 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
source      : w001001.adf 
name        : VALUE 
min value   :   -76 
max value   :  5930
```

The problem appears to be due to `terra` thinking this is a categorical raster, with levels. That's why the plot appears differently. Also:

```
> is.factor(r)
[1] TRUE
```

which shouldn't be true for a numeric raster:

```
> is.factor(rast(matrix(1:12,3,4)))
[1] FALSE
```

but is for one made of letters:

```
> is.factor(rast(matrix(letters[1:12],3,4)))
[1] TRUE
```

I can't find any documentation on how to make `rast` read in as numeric, or how to convert from one to the other (`as.numeric` doesn't work) but adding "0" seems to work:

```
 plot(r+0)
```

[image]

There may be documentation somewhere or this may be changed in a later release, I guess.

[ask your second Q in a separate post]

Comment: Thanks @Spacedman. Can you explain why adding "0" works? I think ultimately I want the raster to read in correctly to be sure no errors when we go to actually work with the values in the raster...

Comment: I can't definitively explain why it works, but I can imagine that at some point `terra` is converting the factor back to numeric to do the addition. The only docs on factors in terra I can find is in `help(terra::levels)` and there's not much in the code either. I strongly suggest you file an issue in the terra bug tracker, explain the problem and link to this Q. The terra dev does use SO so he may see this anyway.

Comment: `terra` is still in development so you have to expect a bit of weirdness and minor hacks to fix things. Adding 0 seems minor enough to not break stuff, except it might result in a large on-disk raster being read into RAM, I guess. Finding the right way to do it, if that exists, would be better, but I don't see any documentation, and other guesses, like `as.numeric(r)` don't work.

Comment: `as.numeric` was a good guess --- but I only added that a week ago!